# Rotate individual triangles on javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotation

I am trying to create six triangles together to form a hexagon and then rotate them. I successfully created a sliced hexagon and I am able to rotate that but I want each slice to behave separately (for example if an object hit a slice, it's size should shrink and the other should stay the same sized). following is my code that is running successfully on the canvas. Can somebody please help me to draw separate triangles with separate references so that I can modify them as needed. I am planing to make the triangles look smaller or bigger using the "lineTo" to draw them of required size and then fill them. please let me know if there is another approach to achieve this. Much appreciated.

```
<script>
var numberOfSides = 6,
size = 100,
Xcenter = 0,
Ycenter = 0,
prevX,
prevY,
startPX,
startPY,
angle = 0.1,
angleChange=Math.PI/180;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo (Xcenter +  size * Math.cos(0), Ycenter +  size *  Math.sin(0));          
startPX = Xcenter +  size * Math.cos(0); 
startPY = Ycenter +  size *  Math.sin(0);

requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function animate(time){
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
ctx.save();

// translate and rotate the canvas
ctx.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);
ctx.rotate(angle); 
for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfSides;i += 1) {
ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
//    ctx.fillStyle = get_random_color();
//    addMessage(get_random_color());
// save the untranslated & unrotated context state



ctx.lineTo(Xcenter,Ycenter);
ctx.lineTo (Xcenter + size * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides), Ycenter + size * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides));
ctx.lineTo (startPX, startPY);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
//    prevX = Xcenter + size * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides);
//    prevY = Ycenter + size * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides);
startPX = Xcenter + size * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides);
startPY = Ycenter + size * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides);
ctx.moveTo(startPX,startPY);
ctx.beginPath();
}

// restore the context to its untranslated & unrotated state
ctx.restore();    
angle+=angleChange;


}
ctx.closePath();
ctx.strokeStyle = "#ffffff";
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.stroke();
//}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to create a `Slice` class and move the paint functions into this class. Now you create for each slice a `Slice` object/instance (`new Slice(...)`) which you can style separately (`slices[0].setColor('red')`). See the snippet below.

I'd suggest to improve the sample below by creating slices with identical coordinates and rotating the slice at it's correct position by a `ctx.rotate`.

```js
    var Slice = function(Xcenter, Ycenter, size, number, numberOfSides) {
        this.scale = 1.0;
        this.color = 'blue';
        this.pos = [];
        this.pos.push({x:Xcenter, y:Ycenter});
        this.pos.push({
            x:Xcenter + size * Math.cos((number+1) * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides),
            y:Ycenter + size * Math.sin((number+1) * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides)
        });
        this.pos.push({
            x: Xcenter + size * Math.cos(number * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides),
            y: Ycenter + size * Math.sin(number * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides)
        });
    };
    Slice.prototype.setScale = function(scale) {
        this.scale = scale;
    };
    Slice.prototype.setColor = function(color) {
        this.color = color;
    };
    Slice.prototype.draw = function(ctx) {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.scale(this.scale,this.scale);
        ctx.beginPath();
        for (var i=0; i<this.pos.length; i++) {
            ctx.lineTo(this.pos[i].x, this.pos[i].y);
        }
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
    };

    function ready() {

        var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

        var numberOfSides = 6,
        size = 100,
        Xcenter = 0,
        Ycenter = 0,
        prevX,
        prevY,
        startPX,
        startPY,
        angle = 0.1,
        angleChange=Math.PI/180;

        var slices = [];
        for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfSides;i += 1) {
            slices.push(new Slice(Xcenter, Ycenter, size, i, numberOfSides));
        }
        slices[0].setScale(0.9);
        slices[0].setColor('red');

        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        function animate(time){
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
            ctx.save();

            // translate and rotate the canvas
            ctx.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);
            ctx.rotate(angle);
            for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfSides;i += 1) {
                slices[i-1].draw(ctx);
            }

            // restore the context to its untranslated & unrotated state
            ctx.restore();
            angle+=angleChange;
        }
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#ffffff";
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.stroke();
    }
```

```html
<body onload="ready();">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked like a charm. It would be great if you can help on couple more things, 1). approach on collision detection on the outer lines of hexagon. 2) if multiple players are playing this simultaneously, each player see himself at the bottom and other relatively positioned to that.

Comment: @rajendersohi Nice to know that my answer was helpful. Concerning the other questions: Please create for every issue another question on StackOverflow.

Comment: Sure i will. Can i post a link to my other question here?

Comment: @rajendersohi It is possible, but unusual. I can find your question by your username.

Comment: I created a new question for that additional help.